# Do stdin and stdout share any resources?

Tags: c++, terminal, stdout, stdin, piping

### Are standard input and standard output independent or not?

Consider a parent program had launched a child, and the parent's standard output was attached to the child's standard input, and the child's standard output was attached to the parent's standard input.

```
        stdin       <- stdout 
parent                        child
        stdout ->      stdin
```

If the child (asynchronously) continually read from its standard input and wrote data to its standard output, but the parent just wrote to the child's standard input and didn't read from the child's standard output at all:

```
        stdin|     << stdout 
parent                       child
        stdout ==>==> stdin
```

would there eventually be a blockage? Do standard input and standard output share a buffer of any kind? Specifically via C++ `std::cin` (istream) and `std::cout` (ostream) if that's needed to answer. Does the standard require they do or do not share such a thing, or does it leave it up to the implementation?

What would happen?

Comment: You should refer to these streams by their Unix names, stdin and stdout , not by their C++ names, when you're talking about redirection and blocking.

Comment: Why would they share a buffer?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart tyvm, edited.

Comment: I would suggest the language-agnostic names for the streams are 'standard input' and 'standard output'.  The name `stdin` is the C language identifier for the standard input file stream, and `stdout` is the C language name for the standard output file stream.  These correspond to similar names in C++: `stdin` corresponding to `std::stdin` from `<cstdio>` (and, I think, `::stdin` from `<stdio.h>`), and also to `std::cin`, though the I/O functions used with `std::cin` are very different from those used with `std::stdout`; and `stdout` corresponding to `std::stdout` (`::stdout`) and `std::cout`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "attach" a file descriptor from a process to a file descriptor of a different process. What you do (if your operating system supports it) is to assign the two file descriptors to the ends of a "pipe". Pipes are not specified anywhere in the C/C++ standard (they are defined by POSIX), and you won't find any standard C/C++ library function which makes any reference to them at all.

As implemented by Unix (and Unix-like) systems, a pipe is little more than a buffer somewhere in the operating system. While the buffer is not full, a process can write data to the input end of the pipe; the data is simply added to the buffer. While the buffer is not empty, a process can read data from the output end of the buffer; the data is removed from the buffer and handed off to the reading process. If a process tries to write to a pipe whose buffer is full or read from a pipe whose buffer is empty, the process "blocks": that is, it is marked by the kernel scheduler as not runnable, and it stays in that state until the pipe can handle its request.

The scenario described in the question needs to involve two pipes. One pipe is used to allow the parent's stdout to send data to the child's stdin, and the other is used to allow the child's stdout to send data to the parent's stdin. These two pipes are wholly independent of each other.

Now, if the parent stops reading from its stdin, but the child continues writing to its stdout, then eventually the pipe buffer will become full. (It actually won't take very long. Pipe buffers are not very big, and they don't grow.) At that point, the child will block trying to write to the pipe. If the child is not multithreaded, then once it blocks, that's it. It stops running, so it won't read from its stdin any more. And if the child stops reading from its stdin, then the other pipe will soon become full and the parent will also block trying to write to its stdout.

So there's no requirement that resources be shared in order to achieve deadlock.

This is a very well-known bug in processes which spawn a child and try to feed data to the child while reading the child's response. If the reader does not keep up with the data produced, then deadlock is likely. You'll find lots of information about it by searching for, for example, "pipe buffer deadlock". Here are a few sample links, just at random:

Raymond Chen, on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx

Right here on StackOverflow (with reference to Python but the issue is identical): [Can someone explain pipe buffer deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381751/can-someone-explain-pipe-buffer-deadlock)

David Glasser, from 2006: http://web.mit.edu/6.033/2006/wwwdocs/writing-samples/unix-DavidGlasser.html ("These limitations are not merely theoretical — they can be seen in practice by the fact that no major form of inter-process communication later developed in Unix is layered on top of pipe.")

Comment: Yes, piping. I didn't even realize that was it. I actually was thinking of a specific program I was writing but the API is pretty high level so it doesn't make it obvious that I'm really using pipes when I do something like this. D'oh. ----- Extremely detailed answer! Thank you very much. ----- No, not theoretical at all, in fact I had to refactor the parent program according to this answer in order to avoid deadlock. It works now though I appreciate the response.