# How to pass the same answer to subprocess.Popen automatically?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to call something like `yes "y" | foo bar`, but using `subprocess.Popen`. Currently I use this:

```
yes = subprocess.Popen(['yes', '""'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['foo', 'bar'], stdin=yes.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But, of course, this won't work on Windows. How can I do this so that it works on every platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[To emulate a shell pipeline `yes "y" | foo bar` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_proc = Popen(['foo', 'bar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
yes_proc = Popen(['yes', 'y'], stdout=foo_proc.stdin)
foo_output = foo_proc.communicate()[0]
yes_proc.wait() # avoid zombies
```

To pipe input in Python (without the `yes` utility), you could use [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331150/4279) or [async. I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572974/4279) where `input_iterator` is `itertools.repeat(b'y' + os.linesep.encode())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
p.stdin.write("yes\nyes\nyes")

In [18]: p.communicate()
Out[18]: ('yes\nyes\nyes', None)
```

You can do this in two threads of course (write in one thread and `Popen` instance reading in another thread).

However, that's not really safe, though:

[Can someone explain pipe buffer deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381751/can-someone-explain-pipe-buffer-deadlock)

Comment: My main problem is that I do not know how many times I need to answer `'yes'`, and your answer does not really help with this