# Run continuous .exe file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to implement a python code where I need to run an external executable file. After some research I found `subprocess` module and tried it. However, when I run the code, the subprocess exits and returns a `CompletedProcess` object, which is not okay for me because the .exe I am working with is actually a **continuous** program where it takes input and generates output until it is closed. (My program will be sending its inputs and recieving the outputs.)

So this code fails.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run("some.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc) # To see what it is.
```

It captures the programs first output in stdout but then quits, rather than expecting new input.

I am also having a problem with the terminology here, this executable I am using is capable of running commands while still being able to recieve new commands, is this called **asynchronous** or **Non-blocking** ?

**To my question**, what is the correct way of handling this ? There are a lot of questions in SO close to this but I could not be sure which were answering my problem or answering it in a modern way (There are very old questions).

It would appear `subprocess` module undergone some changes with Python 3.6.1 https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

So it would be best if you could provide the solution in the newest way, or at least mention the newer way and how it operates.

I am working on Windows 10, Python 3.6.1

**Edit1:** I have come across `subprocess.Popen`, which may be what I need, but I am yet to discover how it is properly used.

**Edit2:** The module `pexpect` seems to be designed for these kind of problems, but I am not sure if using this going to make my time much easier. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can these "inputs" simply be written into the command for the subprocess call?

Comment: @JacobIRR, Yes, forgive me for not mentioning, this is a console application and recieves inputs from stdin directly. I can directly run it and test the inputs, which I need my Python application to do instead of me.

Comment: But the inputs are not pre-determined, I can't give all the inputs when I call the program in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> subprocess.run()
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance.

Since your subprocess doesn't end after initially calling it, you cannot use `run` but need to use `Popen` instead.

You could use something like this:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(exe_path,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while p.poll() is None:
    p.stdin.write(some_command)
    p.stdin.flush()
    out = p.stdout.readline()
```

But note that this can lead to a deadlock as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr):

> **Warning** Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Unfortunately you cannot use `communicate` because this would require you to call the process with all input. I'd give it a try with the version above and see if the buffers really cause problems in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also came across this just before you posted the answer, seems like the only easy solution to my problem. I just need to wrap up these in some function. However I would appreciate more knowledge about this deadlock situation and how to avoid it.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381751/can-someone-explain-pipe-buffer-deadlock) for an explanation of the deadlock problem. The solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) might help avoiding deadlocks by using a separate thread that reads data from the buffer to prevent fill-up.